# How to convert number to month name in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I m trying to convert string number to month name but i searched a lot of resources but it didn't help me.

here is my query

```
SELECT CAST(extract('month'
                    FROM to_date(proforma_invoice_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')) AS VARCHAR) AS proforma_invoice_date
FROM proforma_invoice
```

Here is my output...

[image]

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: why are you storing DATE values in a `varchar` column? That is a really bad idea to begin with.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `to_char()`:

```
to_char(to_date(proforma_invoice_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')), 'Month')
```